# calendar using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a *textbox* and a **calendar** icon right beside it.

I want to show calendar(`datepicker`) when I click on the icon.

I tried using `jquery datepicker`, but it's not working.

Is there a way to achieve this using **ONLY** javascript?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, and can do in about 2lines what would take you 50 in plain JS. What part isn't working? Post some code so people can try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: And jQuery UI Datepicker is not suitable because...?

Comment: There are LOADs of calendar libraries out there. If jQUI datapicker isn't working choose another. Unless you're using jQUI elsewhere in your code it's hardly worth loading if you're only using it for the calendar. It's a hefty piece of resource. IMO obvs.

Comment: This is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5fdqktpf/
No, jquery relevant files are added here. But I did put them in my application and it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get any errors in the console? Did you do any basic debugging of your code yourself?

Comment: I added all the relevant files that I thought I would need. The error message was "undefined, not a function".

Comment: And yes, I did try and debug it. By adding datepicker.setDefaults. Did not work

Comment: Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5fdqktpf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot attach a `datepicker` to an `img`; use a `span`, `div` or `input`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepick').datepicker(); // the inputs id
});
```

> By default, the datepicker calendar opens in a small overlay when the
>   associated text field gains focus. **For an inline calendar, simply
>   attach the datepicker to a div or span**.

Comment: Okay. But I need to open the calendar on the icon click and not on field click

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the solution here easily:
[Jquery Site](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) Click on the view source.